# Installing Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a DELL xps 8940 with NVIDIA(R) GeForce(R) RTX 2060

Tags: nvidia, dell, xps

I've spent my Saturday struggling to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a DELL XPS 8940 with a NVIDIA(R) GeForce(R) RTX 2060.  Finally got it working and will post answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the BIOS settings were configured specifically for Windows.

Here's a link to snap shots with the new BIOS settings.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4A6X.jpg

At one point the BIOS settings got corrupted while attempting to reconfigure them and the motherboard CMOS coin battery had to be removed for ten minutes to reset the BIOS configuration.

Please be aware that many of the security and other modern processor features have been disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I too recently loaded Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a Dell 8940 with a GTX 1660 Ti a 1 TB SSD and a 2 TB SATA.  All of mathew gunther's instructions worked for me but I still got a black screen on boot.  I had to boot into recovery mode (advanced options from GRUB) and search for "additional drivers" and change the Nouveau driver to the NVIDIA 470 driver.

Also, for others who are interested, I wanted to put windows on half the SATA drive and Ubuntu on the SSD, and the other half of the SATA.  I did this using AOMEI Backupper (had to buy it for $45) to back up the SSD to SATA and leave the rest of the space free.  I tried using Windows restore to no avail.  I probably could have done the same with Clonezilla for free.  Then when installing Ubuntu, I removed the existing partitions on the SSD and allowed it to install there.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1196960)